# Get all elements that match a specific attribute value, but match any tag or attribute name with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to get all elements that match a specific attribute value, but match any tag or attribute name with BeautifulSoup. If so does anyone know how to do it?

Here's an example of how I'm trying to do it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

text_to_match = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bettss3/images/003obzt0t_w1200_h1200.jpg'
url = 'https://www.betts.com.au/item/37510-command.html?colour=chocolate'
r = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
possibles = bs.find_all(None, {None: text_to_match})
print(possibles)
```

This gives me an empty list [].

If I replace `{None: text_to_match}` with `{'href': text_to_match}` this example will give some results as expected. I'm trying to figure out how to do this without specifying the attribute's name, and only matching the value.

Comment: post a sample and testable html fragment, and expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've modified the example so it's testable

Comment: And what is the value to match on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to find_all with no limitation and filter those who doesn't correspond to your needs, as such

```
text_to_match = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bettss3/images/003obzt0t_w1200_h1200.jpg'
url = 'https://www.betts.com.au/item/37510-command.html?colour=chocolate'
r = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
tags = [tag for tag in bs.find_all() if text_to_match in str(tag)]
print(tags)
```

this sort of solution is a bit clumsy as you might get some irrelevant tags, you make your text a bit more tag specific by:

```
text_to_match = r'="https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bettss3/images/003obzt0t_w1200_h1200.jpg"'
```

which is a bit closer to the str representation of a tag with attribute

Comment: In the comprehension, you can also do `if text_to_match in tag.attrs.values()`

Comment: This looks like a great way to make the same thing happen, thanks!